# IBM MobileFirst - Direct update fails when update size is larger than 400 MB

Tags: ipad, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

We are using IBM MobileFirst 7.1 for our hybrid app.
We have noticed that on the iPad ,direct update fails when the file size is around 400MB. 
Why is there such a limit in place and is there a way to get around this ?

[image: prompt for update - update size is 410.6MB]

[image: update fails]

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no limit to direct update size. MFP server can serve direct update requests upto 250MB/second.
However many factors need to be considered - your server's performance, network, free space on your device etc. Most important of all, is why your direct update is in the range of 400 + MB - and by extension the size of the application on your device and on the server.

Note that direct update is a way to quickly update your web resources ( Javascript/CSS/HTML) over the air. Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_direct_updates_app_versions_to_mob.html).

- If your direct update archive size is 400 MB +, your actual application size will be much more - which puts enormous I/O strain on your MFP server and runtime DB. There can be runtime synchronization issues in loading your application content every time server reboots.
- If 400MB direct update has to be served to all your connecting devices, the server will be choked on resources.
- While at it, for such a huge file size it is more than likely the network may not hold until completely downloaded. End users may have to resume the download multiple times - all the while the application cannot be used.
- Finally the end user's device should have enough free space to keep the downloaded archive and enough space to unarchive it.

The issue with direct update you have seen is only a symptom. You should probably re-consider your application design.

Specifically:

a) Why is a hybrid application so big ( possibly 500 MB+)? Consider the time it will take to download your application from Store.

b) Is your server sufficiently tuned to handle the massive load?

[Performance tuning](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_performance_tuning.html)

[Optimization and tuning of MobileFirst Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html)

[Optimization of MobileFirst Server project databases](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_wl_server_databases.html)

c) Are you embedding audio/video content into your application?

d) You can try minification of your JS and CSS files to reduce the size:

[Minification of JS and CSS files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_minification.html)

As a thumb rule, try to keep the direct update size to about a few 10s of MBs. If it is close to 100MB or more then you can consider going through AppStore or PlayStore.

If you would still like to avoid application resubmission, you can use CDN to serve your direct update:

[Serving direct update requests from a CDN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_direct_update_requests_from_cdn.html)

Note that this only takes the strain off your MFP server - in serving the direct update request from all end users. The free space and network considerations of the end user does not change. Runtime synchronization issues at MFP server are still a possibility.